# How do I push a branch that is very heavy (123M) to gitlab?

Tags: git, ssh, https, gitlab

I have to push all changes I've been making to my repository over at gitlab, I've created a new branch from master called develop

```
git checkout develop
```

Afterward, I made my changes (comprehended by several commits) which included a bunch of images and CSS / js files.

I'm using ssh to connect with my repository. To push my contents I use the following command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin develop
```

After running the command my console hangs with this message:

```
Counting objects: 388, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (274/274), done.
Writing objects:  45% (178/388), 5.76 MiB | 230.00 KiB/s
```

I had a similar issue before so I added an https remote to this repository called 'secure' and tried to push my changes through it however when I try to push my changes the following error occurs:

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (274/274), done.
Writing objects: 100% (388/388), 20.91 MiB | 53.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 388 (delta 156), reused 276 (delta 95)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error (-12): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried increasing my post buffer size:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000
```

But these efforts didn't work.

Comment: `which included a bunch of images and CSS / js files` ... binary content such as this is not well suited to be versioned inside Git.  Consider storing your multimedia files somewhere else (e.g. in Perforce or maybe S3).

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, I usually don't use S3 nor do I have an account there, In the past I didn't have issues uploading a few images to gilab, they are only images used for the landing page of a website. Having said that, I'm not close minded and I'm glad to hear suggestions,  is there any service compatible with digitalocean's services to upload images?

Comment: One setup some use is Git for source files and Perforce for images.